# Difference between Promise and async/await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

What is the difference between the two functions ?

```
function src() {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(console.log("done! 1 ")), 4000);
 });
```

}

```
async function src() {
     setTimeout(() => console.log("done! 1 "), 4000);
}
```

Comment: The second function cannot be `await`-ed as a "pause". It just fires the timer and finishes.

Answer (score 1):

The second one will return a Promise that resolves immediately.

The first one will return a Promise that resolves after 4 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

In the first one, once the function is called a promise is returned with resolved state set in a timeout. So when the 4 sec timer ends (ofc without any errors) the resolved function triggers with text logged to the console.

Second one will too return a promise but of no certain use. On being called, it will just trigger the timer to print text after 4 sec. No promise functionality is used here.

Answer (score 0):

Async/Await is just syntactic sugar for promises. Async/Await implicitly uses Promises. Async/Await just makes working with Promises easier.

That being said, your second functions doesn't make use of Async/Await properly. There's no await statement, but it's impossible to use an await statement directly with setTimeout anyway.

So, if you still want to use Async/Await you would have to write your own timeout function that would resemble your first function.

```js
function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function src() {
    await timeout(4000);
    console.log("done! 1 ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you create new Promise you get to parameters **resolve & reject**. Whenever its success case you resolve on failure you reject. In case of resolve it will go to `then` & in case of reject it will go to `catch`. Promise is more over like real world promise (it could either be completed [`resolved`] or broken [`reject`]).

Though async & await helps you do asynchronous operations in JS. Whenever in `async` function it encounters `await` it will wait for that code to be executes and then will move to next line.

Refer to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_Kr9OSfDeU) for better understanding along with example.